# rsimgetrtp doesn't work when i compile my gui to standalone exe

Tags: matlab, user-interface, simulink

i have a problem with *rsimgetrtp*.

It should work with

```
rtp=rsimgetrtp('modelname','AddTunableParamInfo','on')
```

but it doesn't. I get an error when i compile my files to make standalone application. error says *"Undefined function or method 'find_system' for input arguments of type 'char'"*

Before compiling everything works fine. My GUI and exe files exchange data perfectly, but after compilinig i get error. I tried google it but  found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simulink functionality is not compilable.  You'll need to create a dummy/placeholder parameter structure before you go through the compile process and store it somewhere (most likely in a mat-file), then load that into your deployed app. rather than trying to use rsimgetrtp within the deployed app.

Comment: thank you, it worked... but now i have problem with _rsimsetrtpparam_ function
my code is
a1=get(handles.abroj,'String');
a1=str2num(a1);
load('rtptunableparaminfo.mat');
rtp=rtptunablevariable;
rtp=rsimsetrtpparam(rtp,'a',a1);

when i compile it and start exe file i get this error message

"undefiend function or method 's1' for input arguments of type 'struct'

Comment: Simulink functionality is not compilable. You cannot use any Simulink related functions in your application.  You need to look at the parameter structure, determine which of its fields need to be modified, and modify it using standard MATLAB (not Simulink) functionality.

Comment: i see, i thought that rsimsetrtpparam is a function for exe-files not for simulink models, my bad.. i haven't had much sleep lately :)



thank you once again mr.Phil

Comment: mr.Phil if I may ask you for advice once again...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29543087/why-cant-i-tune-tunable-parameter-l-for-block-series-rlc-branch