# Why can't I tune tunable parameter "L" for block "Series RLC branch"?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, exe, simulink

I made exe file from Simulink model (I used rsim, tunable parameter on). Before this i made a standalone application with exe  file that had block "constant" and everything worked great. I used "rsimgetrtp" and followed mr.Phil advices. But now when I need to make a more complex exe simulation with GUI i get warning that says some parameters can't be tunable.

"Warning: Reducing expression 'Lk' in parameter field
'Inductance' of 'sestpulsni/Lk3' to its numerical equivalent because
this field is marked not tunable. This expression resolves to tunable
variables (Lk (base workspace)). You will be unable to tune this
expression during model execution"

Is there anyway I can make it tunable? or if I can't what should i do to make a standalone GUI with exe and tunable parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are using a block from the SimPowerSystems library.

Unfortunately, many (most? all?) of the blocks in that library take all the parameters, throw them into a large pot, mix them together, and then use the resulting [Mung](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mung_(computer_term)) to perform the simulation.  There is no way to use the block and avoid that problem.

The only thing you can do is implement your own block, with the required functionality, which keeps the variables individual and hence tunable.

Comment: It computes a state-space representation of the electrical network prior to simulation, which is why it isn't tunable

Comment: thank you guys for you help, i have another idea that i'm not sure is possible. Can I unmask blocks from SimPower and then try to do some "magic"? As i understand those blocks are on masked Simulink models.